# Issue with resolving a type in castle that depends on IList

Tags: castle-windsor

I am trying to resolve an object (Context class) which has a constructor dependency on an IList but I am not able to resolve( see exception below). Can anyone explain why is this? Is there an issue with castle and .net generic exceptions? Thanks for replies

```
public class Context : IContext
    {

        public Context(
            IApplicationSite applicationSite,
            IList<Currency> currencies)
        {
        }
    }
```

And this is my IOC registration:

```
var _container = new WindsorContainer();

_container.Kernel.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>();            

    _container.Register(
    Component.For<IRepository>()
    .ImplementedBy<Repository>()
    .Named("repository"));

_container.Register(
    Component
    .For<IList<Currency>>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<IRepository>().GetCurrencies())
    .Named("currencies"));

_container.Register(
    Component
    .For<IApplicationSite>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<IRepository>().GetApplicationSite())
    .Named("applicationSite"));

_container.Register(
    Component.For<IContext>()
    .ImplementedBy<Context>()
    .Named("Context"));

var _context = _container.Resolve<IContext>();
```

When I try to resolve context I get the following exception:

```
Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DependencyResolverException : Could not resolve non-optional dependency for 'Context' (ClassLibraryCastle.Context). 
Parameter 'currencies' type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[ClassLibraryCastle.Currency, ClassLibraryCastle, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'
```

Comment: It is all explained [in the FAQ](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.FAQ.ashx#Why_is_Windsor_not_able_to_inject_array_or_list_of_components_8).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a method of resolving a dependency on IList - using dyanamic parameters

```
_container.Register(
    Component.For<IContext>()
        .ImplementedBy<Context>()
        .Named("context")
        .DynamicParameters((k, parameters) => // dynamic parameters
        {
           parameters["currencies"] = k.Resolve<IList<Currency>>();
        }));
```